# Iterate array using range

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is what I want to do

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[1] = 0
a[2] = 0
```

one way to do this is to loop

```
(1..2).each { |x| x = 0 }
```

is there a way to do this somehow with ranges or splats? something like

```
a[(1..2)] = 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[1..2] = [0] * 2
p a #[1, 0, 0, 4]
```

You can't just type `a[1..2] = 0` at line 2, cause the array `a` will become `[1, 0, 4]`

Comment: `a[1..2] = 0, 0`, `a[1,2] = 0,0`, `a[1..2] = *[0,0]`

Answer (score 2):

Or, with `Array#fill`

```
a.fill(0, 1..2)
```

Answer (score 1):

**With range**

```
ary = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ary[1..2] = [0,0]
```

**Using [start, length]**

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[1,2] = [0,0]
```